# CV font size is not readable when printed

Tags: feature-request, bug, developer-story, cv-export

I tried to print my CV, and it didn't turn out so well:

[image]

There is an "Export to PDF" function; but that doesn't allow me to modify the size of the text.  Can you have an Export to `.docx` or something I can use to make a printable version of this? (Export to .docx would also be useful because there are whole sections of my resume I don't necessarily want to send someone: Likes/dislikes, objective statement, technical skills, books I read, etc).

The font, as it stands when you're trying to print a CV, is unreadable.  "Likes and Dislikes" is 8pt font, text is 10pt, and only the personal narrative is approaching a readable size.

Comment: FWIW that looks like a normal printed document, font size-wise. Is your specific issue that you want to export the CV to a readily-editable format (e.g. .docx, .txt, or .rtf), that you want to print the CV from the browser, or that you want to modify the text of the CV as it is displayed on the browser? It's unclear which, exactly, is your primary concern w/ the way the question is currently written.

Comment: The default font for print is a 10pt font. That's uncharacteristically small.

Comment: (Subjective opinion: a CV is too important to trust any external service to write it, instead yourself. My problem wouldn't be the font size, but that nothing can I trust more what I wrote myself. Note, typically employers don't say the real reason of a rejection, and often even they don't know it.)

Comment: [[meta-tag:bug]] I tried to print my CV, but there was no banana included.

Comment: Where on earth did you get that big banana from? ;)

Comment: Is the banana for scale... or _actually_ because you were hungry when taking the pic?

Comment: @coldspeed I realized something funny, as he said he is in Virginia, so the time there is four ahead of UTC, so when he posted this, it was lunch time for him

Comment: Either that CV is the size of a small Banana or that Banana is humongous

Comment: I really like the  in the picture :D